# Construction of segment of given length through an intersection of two circles

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

"Through an intersection point of two circles, draw a secant such that its segment inside the given disks is congruent to a given length.

Hint: Construct a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the segment between the centers of the given disks,
and one of the legs is congruent to a half of the given length".

[image]
Let's say segment EF is given and we have to construct secant through point K such that its length inside disks A and B equals segment EF.

Many thanks for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "inside the given discs"? I would assume it is impossible if $EF$ is larger than the diameter of a disc.

Comment: it would be impossible if EF is larger than sum of diameters. so secant must be bounded by intersecting points with circles

Comment: Where should be the endpoints of the segment?

Comment: Both endpoints could be on same circle or on different circles

Comment: I would assume that the endpoints should be on the different circles. Only in this case the problem makes sense.

Comment: No I think the solution covers all cases

Comment: Then for certain lengths of the segment multiple  solutions are possible (with $K$ being either endpoint or inner point of the segment).

Comment: That's right. I'm not sure how to use the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

[image]

$ACSR$ is a rectangle. Do you see why $AC=RS=\frac12 LM$?

> Solution:
> construct - as was suggested - a right triangle $ABC$ whose hypotenuse $AB$ is the segment between the centers of the given disks, and one of the legs ($AC$) is congruent to $\frac12EF$. Draw through the point $K$ a line parallel to $AC$. It will intersect the circles in the points $L$ and $M$. Then $LM=EF$. The construction is possible only if $\frac12EF<AB$, in which case there are two solutions according to the number of possibilities to construct the triangle $ABC$.

Comment: Yes I see. The solution is very nice.. Thanks